# Como agregar componentes basados en la ruta en Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js

Estoy intentando mostrar un componente basandose en la ruta, por ejemplo, mostrar el componente Contacto con la ruta `/contact` dentro del componente principal (index) para que  el contenido del componente `contact` salga dentro del div `#box`

```
pages
|    index.vue
|    contact.vue
```

intente usando `<nuxt-child>` de esta manera

index.vue

```
<div id="box">
    <NuxtLink to="/contact">contacto</NuxtLink>
    <nuxt-child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que quieres hacer, en Nuxt existen los **layouts** que sirven para envolver las páginas con otros componentes como una navegación, un pie de página, etc.

Lo único que tienes que hacer es crear una carpeta `layouts` y dentro de la misma tienes que crear un archivo `default.vue` que va a ser el layout aplicado por defecto a todas tus páginas.

En este nuevo archivo agregas todos los componentes que quieras que aparezcan en todas las páginas y colocas el componente `<Nuxt />` donde quieras que se inyecte el contenido de las páginas.

Ej:

```
// ./layouts/default.vue
<template>
    <div id="box">
        <NuxtLink to="/contact">contacto</NuxtLink>
        <Nuxt />
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Eso ya lo estoy haciendo, del layout `default.vue` esta en index.vue, lo que quiero hacer es nada mas que aparezca otra pagina dentro de una pagina y no de un layout